# Temporarily disable Javascript for inactive Chrome tabs (except for whitelisted urls) - until active again?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, speed, chromium, tabbed-browsing

I often am researching stuff, and need lots of tabs open but Chrome can get very slow.
I notice that often memory seems to be increasing for chrome processes - even ones I am not interacting with. I suspect this is because of Javascript.

Is there a way to temporarily disable Javascript or other resources for Chrome tabs I am not using, except for a whitelist of sites like GMail, and Facebook? (Some sites are webapps doing background tasks I find useful - like waiting for instant messages.)

I would be content with just an image of many web pages, rather than a full dynamic tab just sitting there using memory. I only need it to be dynamic when interacting with it.

I wish Chrome would keep inactive tabs in separate processes and just pause some of it's processes I'm not using.

Side note, probably separate issue: I often find killing the Flash plugin can speed things up too.

Comment: did you find a solution working in current chrome (v45)?

Answer (score 5):

I wanted something like this but I only wanted to pause the JavaScript v8 context for inactive tabs as this is less disruptive to the page than turning JavaScript off. As what I found also somewhat answers the OP's question I'll put what I found here.

I found out that doing that was possible with [chrome.experimental.debugger](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.debugger.html) and they provide [an sample extension which uses the debugger which creates an icon which allows one to pause and unpause the current tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#debugger).

I haven't yet tested whether that could be adapted to automatically pause tabs when inactive and unpause them when they become active.

Comment: Great, so we're getting closer it seems!

Comment: It also might be possible for a program to detect the current tab in use and slow down other processes by pausing them (cpulimit on Linux is great). Though I suppose finding the processes for the current tab may be tricky (or rather finding the Chrome processes that are not involved in the current tab). I guess a Chrome extension would be good. I wish the whole browser was scriptable in JS...

Answer (score 2):

```
Wrench Menu > Options > Under the Hood > Privacy 'Content settings' > Javascript
```

In the above section, you can completely turn off javascript for all sites and then mark as exception ***the whitelist of sites like GMail, and Facebook***.

There is no way Google Chrome will automatically figure which tabs are active and disable javascript for the inactive ones. Not yet anyway.

[image]

Comment: I consider this overkill because I think Javascript should be everywhere, I want my web access to be dynamic, but thanks anyhow :)

Answer (score 0):

In March 2017 (Chrome 57), Chrome added some automation of this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs

Background tabs are now limited to 10ms each, on average, of processing each second.